# Orbit, Stabiliser help please?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $Q$ denote the rectangle with the vertices $C_1=(2,1), C_2=(-2,1), C_3=(-2,-1)$ and $C_4=(2,-1)$.

Describe the elements of the symmetry group $G$, of $Q$. Note that $G$ permutes the edges of $Q$. Give the orbit and stabiliser subgroup for the edge from $C_1$ to $C_2$.

Comment: Have you decided on any symmetries in the group, or its size, or anything?

Comment: it says permuting the edges not the vertices so taking a guess I'm guessing its linked to the dihedral group $D_{2}$. But not to sure.

Comment: Yeah, if $D_2$ is defined the way I expect, this is exactly $D_2$. The symmetries permute both the edges and vertices, they were just calling attention to the fact that the edges are permuted as well (and therefore each have stabilizer subgroups, and orbits, under the action).

Comment: So would i be right in saying $D_{2}$ has order 4. if so i still don't understand how you find the Orbit and the Stabiliser of the group G. its just the theory in general i don't really understand properly.

Comment: say i fix the edge from C1 to C2, only the edges C1 to C4 and C2 to C3 can permute would that be right as C3 to C4 can't permute as C1-C2 is fixed?

Comment: Exactly; you only have three non-identity symmetries: Two reflections that permute a single pair of opposite edges, one of which you mentioned, and a rotation (that's the composition of those reflections).

Comment: and a rotation of $\pi$? okay so now i have all of the symmetries and rotations. how do i get the final answer of the orbit and stabiliser? I'm guessing orbit x stabiliser =4? the order of $D_{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two of our symmetries,

[image]

I'll call the first $f_H$ for "flip horizontally", and $f_V$ for "flip vertically". Note that, like you mentioned in the comments, we also have a rotation of $\pi$ about the center, which is either composition $f_Hf_V = f_Vf_H$.

To think about the orbit of an edge, it's helpful that the edges split into two pairs: The vertical pair, and the horizontal pair. We could either see what happens applying $f_H, f_V$ and $f_Hf_V$ to a given vertical edge, or we could note that no symmetry is going to take an edge of length $2$ to an edge of length $4$, leaving only two possibilities for orbit sizes ($1$ or $2$). It shouldn't be hard to narrow down which is the case.

For the stabilizer, what symmetries fix a vertical edge? Obviously the identity, but are there any others, out of the three? (Of course, using the orbit-stabilizer theorem, and that there are $4$ symmetries, we can check our answer to make sure it all fits together).

Comment: Would we have an orbit size of 2 and also a stabiliser size of 2? Then orbit stabiliser theorem to check would be $|Stab_{G} (Q)| \times |Orb_{G} (Q)|=4$ = $2 \times 2$?

Comment: Yes, exactly! And that'll be the case for any edge you want to focus on.

Comment: Thanks, i had no clue before. But would this be the same method for vertices for any dihedral group size?

Comment: Yeah, thinking in terms of an $n$-gon geometrically, something like this always works; even more nicely for $D_n$ with $n \geq 3$, as $D_2$ is really the black sheep of the family. Slightly different things will happen depending on whether $n$ is even or odd, but just drawing pictures using triangle/pentagon as the basis for odd $n$, and square/hexagon for even $n$ should give you plenty of intuition about the general case.